# Анимация. Увеличение и уменьшение длины линии

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function Nit(x, y, len) {
    this.x = x; // координата х
    this.y = y; // координата у
    this.len = len;
    this.draw = function(context, color, globalAlpha) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.globalAlpha = globalAlpha;
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = color;
      context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      context.lineTo(this.x, this.y + len);
      context.stroke();
    };
  }


  function NachNit() {
    var nitP = new Nit(115, 55, 120);
    var nitL = new Nit(55, 60, 430);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("example");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    nitP.draw(context, "#000000", 1);
    nitL.draw(context, "#000000", 1);
  }

  function Go() {}


  NachNit();
  $('#Go').click(Go);

});
```

```css
#Go {
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Go" value="GO" />
<canvas id="example" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Имеется код, в котором содержится описание линий(одна - короче, другая - длиннее). Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Go" длины линий изменились(длинная стала меньше, короткая - длиннее).Анимация...чтобы было видно как меняются длины этих линий. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Или можно каким-нибудь другим способ создать такую анимацию?

Answer (score 1):

Подобная анимация с использованием css. В canvas подобное можно сделать с использованием setTimeout

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('.line').each(function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
        $(item).toggleClass('short').toggleClass('long');
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative:
    
}
#button {
    position: absolute; left: 200px;    
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  
}
#button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.line {
    position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 30px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.line-2 {
    left: 100px;
}
.line.long { 
    height: 300px;
}
.line.short {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="line line-1 long"></div>
    <div class="line line-2 short"></div>
    <div id="button">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код `$('.line').each( ... );` можно сократить до `$('.line').toggleClass('short long');`